# How can I align the text in the same space when the word are wrapped?

Tags: visual-studio-code, whitespace, word-wrap

[image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOdlM.jpg)

I was looking forward to how can I maintain their spaces if they are wrapped when resized. For example, the `bg-center` must be just below the `<div className="----"`. How can I make that?

I already tried going through settings and searching in google but nothing matches my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have `"editor.wrappingIndent": "none"` in your settings. Try setting it to something else like `"same"`, `"indent"`, or `"deepIndent"`.

If you want the setting value of your choice to only take effect for JSX files specifically, then wrap the settings in a `"[javascriptreact]": { ... }` block in settings.json.